# how to apply an external url with django template

Tags: python, django, templates, url, external

I am new to `Django`. I want to ask a basic question.

I have an `anchor` tag in the template

```
<a href="www.abc.com">website</a>
```

when I get the rendered `template` in the webpage, I get an `url` like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/my_current_page/www.abc.com
```

and actually it goes to the same `url`, while in html I can only find the `href` to be equal to:

```
www.abc.com
```

I also added `target=_blank` to open in the new page. Is this fine the way I am doing this?

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with Django, just standard HTML semantics.

Comment: Thanks daniel. I am just starting django, Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to declare the anchor like this:

```
<a href="http://www.abc.com">website</a>
```

Otherwise the browser will interpret it like a *relative url* and will happen what you just explained.